# When using ruby and cucumber does it limit things I can do with ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Basically are there things I should avoid doing in ruby that may break cucumber. 
Bonus points if you can make me understand cucumber more as someone who went from c# to picking up ruby.

Comment: Cucumber is just a testing framework written in Ruby. Therefore, anything you do in Ruby can be tested by Cucumber.

Comment: But are there things I should not do,  perhaps global variables,  or anything that could potentially cause problems down the line in development?

Comment: *should* is relatively subjective. There are some really complex and incredibly stupid things you could do that *might* cause something to go wrong, but I have never heard of a case where someone's source code broke a proper testing framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things "I should avoid doing in ruby that may break cucumber"?  No.  [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) is a language-agnostic testing framework.  Cucumber's goal is to express use cases in human-readable language that serves as both business specifications and executable test scenarios.  In fact, [cucumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)) was initially forked out of rspec, so it's a product of the the ruby open-source community.  You'll likely run into some gotchas along the way, but there's no magic bullet.  You just have to read the docs (of which there are plenty) and ride the learning curve.